# Android multidex not supporting with proguard

Tags: android, proguard

I updated all my built tools, supportlibrary and google Play services.
But still I am getting the following error:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:shrinkReleaseMultiDexComponents'
>
> java.io.IOException: The output jar [app\build\intermediates\multi-dex\release\componentClasses.jar] must be specified after an input jar, or it will be empty.

I am able to fix this by setting `minifyEnabled` to `false`, but that is not what I want. Does anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: Have you found solution?

Comment: I released with minifyEnabled  with false.

Comment: have you find anything or not ?? please reply must stuck on the same problem ??

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Finally i able generate APK with

> minifyEnabled to true

Actually the issue was some duplicate classes given some warning which i didn't noticed.

For me, i added

> -dontwarn com.aphidmobile.**

in proguard-rules.pro, Same way you have to specify which libraries producing duplicate warning.

It worked Great !

Comment: what is aphidmobile? is it some lib you are using?

Comment: have you find anything or not ?? please reply must stuck on the same problem ??